# Why does std::ws block although the EOF flag is set?

Tags: c++, stream, iostream

If I run the following code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> once, it prints `EOF flag is set` but does not exit after that. Obviously, the second call of `std::ws` seems to wait for further input, **although** the internal EOF flag is set.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cin >> std::ws;

  if(std::cin.eof())
    std::cout << "EOF flag is set\n";

  std::cin >> std::ws;

  return 0;
}
```

If I replace the second `std::cin >> std::ws;` line with

```
float f;
std::cin >> f;
```

the program does **not** wait, but exits immediately.

Is there anything in the standard which would explain this discrepancy? Furthermore, is there any way to make `std::ws` behave differently?

Comment: Maybe a compiler bug?

Comment: @ph4nt0m - The program works fine in VC2013 Express (Windows).  If it is a problem, use `if (std::cin.good()) std::cin >> std::ws;`

Comment: Thanks for checking this, @MichaelJ. Looks like your assumption was correct, Matt. I'm using g++ 4.8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this chunk:

```
    while (!std::cin.eof()) {
        std::cin >> std::ws;
    }

std::cout << "EOF flag is set\n";
```

This repeatedly reads from `cin` while `cin.eof` is `false`.

Comment: I'll leave this question open for some more time, in case somebody knows something more specific about this "bug". If not, I'll accept your answer as a workaround.

Comment: This is not a workaround. In fact this is how you can solve your problem, as the code in your question was waiting for input after you have reached the end of the input. After you reach the end of your input you will not receive anything into your std::ws and will wait for infinity for an input. Sorry for not explaining this in the answer.

Comment: But have a look at what Michael J and Matt McNabb suggested in their comments above. When compiling with VC2013, std::ws does not wait for further input. Surely, only one of those behaviours can be correct (according to the standard).

Comment: Well, I have not been working with C++ for a lot of years, however, I can tell you that it has many different compilers. I do not know why is it working in Michael J's case and I am almost sure this is not a compiler bug, as I would expect exactly the behavior you are experiencing. I have been dealing with many languages and many libraries, so, in my opinion the compiler of MattMcNabb has a bug, not yours.

Comment: @LajosArpad I didn't compile it, I'm commenting on the original post. I read the C++ standard and it appears to say that if `eofbit` is set , then `>> std::ws` should do nothing  (although it is always difficult to be sure exactly what the `iostreams` section of the standard is saying!)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, yes, that's right, but the "it should do nothing" could mean that it does not read a line and wait for infinity. Also, it could mean that it does not even wait. The ambigous statement in your next-to-last comment actually proves a point: It is not clear in the standard what should happen in this case and it depends on the people implementing the compiler. In fact, intuitively I would expect the program to wait for infinity in this case. If I misunderstood the quote, then I would be greatful if you would show the place where you have read about this case.